# Using Bayes' Theorem to calculate if a number is prime if it passed a primality test

Tags: probability, prime-numbers

According to this, I can use Bayes theorem to calculate if $n$ is composite given that it passed the Miller-Rabin primality test: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Accuracy_of_the_test

Here is the section reproduced:

Let $X$ represent event that $n$ is composite

Let $Y$ represent event that $n$ passed the Miller-Rabin test

$P(X|Y)=\frac{P(Y|X)P(X)}{P(Y|X)P(X)+P(Y|X')P(X')}$

I can estimate $P(X)$ using the Prime Number Theory if I know the value of $n$. How do I get the other probabilities?

Comment: no, you can get a probability under certain assumptions about the distribution of primes. Not conclusive. There are methods for proving a number is prime, and methods for proving a number is composite when no prime factors have been found.